# How to only select if 2 record are after another

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I don't even don't how to ask this question but I'll show in example what I am trying to achieve.

```
 ID  NAME   ACTIVITY  TIMESTAMP
 1    ..      book      timestamp
 1    ..      eat       timestamp
 1    ..      sleep     timestamp

 2    ..      apple     timestamp
 2    ..      eat       timestamp
 2    ..      sleep     timestamp
 2    ..      book      timestamp

 3    ..      eat       timestamp
 3    ..      sleep     timestamp
 3    ..      book      timestamp
 3    ..      sleep     timestamp

 4    ..      eat       timestamp1
 4    ..      sleep     timestamp1
 4    ..      sleep     timestamp2
 4    ..      eat       timestamp2
```

I need to select only if next record after `eat` is `sleep` and they both have same `timestamp`and `ID`

so output would be. for this example lets they all have same timestamp. when `ID` = `4` it happens twice but it has different `timestamp`.

```
 ID  NAME   ACTIVITY  TIMESTAMP

 1    ..      eat        timestamp
 1    ..      sleep      timestamp

 2    ..      eat        timestamp
 2    ..      sleep      timestamp

 3    ..      eat        timestamp
 3    ..      sleep      timestamp

 4    ..      eat        timestamp1
 4    ..      sleep      timestamp1
 4    ..      sleep      timestamp2
 4    ..      eat        timestamp2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analytical [`LAG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) and [`LEAD`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions074.htm) functions will do the trick:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Activity, Timestamp
FROM (
  SELECT
    ID,
    Name,
    Activity,
    Timestamp,
    LAG(Activity) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Timestamp ORDER BY Activity) AS PriorActivity,
    LEAD(Activity) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Timestamp ORDER BY Activity) AS NextActivity
  FROM Activity
  WHERE Activity IN ('eat', 'sleep')
)
WHERE (Activity = 'eat' and NextActivity = 'sleep')
   OR (Activity = 'sleep' AND PriorActivity = 'eat')
```

The inner query excludes any activity that isn't `eat` or `sleep`, and it captures the prior (`LAG`) and next (`LEAD`) activity for the `ID` and `Timestamp`, ordered by the activity name - which happens to fit nicely because `eat` sorts before `sleep`.

The outer query just makes sure that `eat` is followed by `sleep` and `sleep` is preceded by `eat`. Because of the inner query's partitioning, that will only be the case where both types are found under the same `ID` and `Timestamp`.

If you have any questions about the query, try running the inner query on its own - that will show the raw data that's filtered by the outer query.

Comment: Brilliant work thanks, but when I run the whole query I get no rows selected, and when I only run inner query I get lots of data, and I know there some times when timestamp is same for both sleep and eat for many IDs.

Comment: just extra note, in PriorActivity and NextActivty I do not see `sleep` and `eat` in same row, it is in next row.

Comment: Hi @Mowgli, I must have misunderstood what your data looks like, so can you check out [this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9ac64/3) and let me know if your data looks different than my test data? Once I get a better handle on the data I'm sure we can get this working.

Comment: Hi Ed, here is img of my inner query data note the table name from. http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5326/8782392849_e7e1d5bc77_o.png thanks

Comment: so for that row 3rd and 4th from bottom should be selected by outter query.

Comment: @Mowgli - sorry about the delay. I'm tied up for the next half hour or so; I'll take a look as soon as I'm free again.

Comment: Ed Thanks a lot for taking out time to look into this. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi @Mowgli - I've got it. My answer above depended on `eat` being alphabetically before `sleep`. Your actual data is the other way around. Try this in outer query `WHERE` clause: `WHERE (Event_Type = 'ETR_CHANGE' AND PriorActivity = 'CREW_ETR_COMMENT_CHANGE') OR (Event_Type = 'CREW_ETR_COMMENT_CHANGE' AND NextActivity = 'ETR_CHANGE')`. It worked for me here.

Comment: Thanks a lot man you are awesome. that solution totally worked me. I just have one more bug I need to fix. sometimes data in oracle comes with delay. for example in the image see the orange circle http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8122/8794443651_1ff0f9f7a1_o.png. it has 1 second difference. that is also good data. is there way to add code, if timestamp difference is `<=10` `less than or equal to 10 seconds` and still consider this condition? thanks again

Comment: Hi @Mowgli, I'm not sure if I can get a sliding 10-second window to work with this approach. I'll play with it a bit and see if I can think of something - this was an interesting question to start with and it just got a lot more interesting :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30513/discussion-between-mowgli-and-ed-gibbs)

Comment: I can't chat right now. I'll have time in an hour or so, but first I'll see if there's a quick answer. I'll get back to you soon.

Comment: sure whenever I just wanted to continue discussion in there, thanks

Comment: Hi @Mowgli, I think I figured this out. It's not radically different but there are definitely some changes. There's a SQL Fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fbf6d/1) with the new query. There are also comment lines explaining the changes. My day unfortunately gets more complicated, so I'll be unavailable starting about 15 minutes from now. Please give the new query a try. It works against the data from before, plus your two new entries, but I haven't tested it beyond that. If there are any problems just let me know and I'll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, this is just genius work. I'll need to spend some time to understand your code. Thanks again.